# Which God has the 'Bird is the Word' dance emote?

Tags: smite

I've been pondering on this for the last hour or two, I can't remember at all which god it is and it's bugging me.

Comment: I didn't know that existed, maybe Ra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dance you are talking about is done by **Hun Batz,** but the actual reference for that dance is NOT "Bird is the Word".

It is a dance called 'The Monkey' that is known also as 'Johnny Bravo's' dance, and can be seen [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3DQ1WCtZqA)

Comment: That makes sense, I don't often play Hun Batz. Thanks :D